# Mongo random sort and match

Tags: mongodb

I do the following:

```
db.users.deleteMany({});

db.users.insert({"name":"paul","gender":"m", "age": 20});
db.users.insert({"name":"jack","gender":"m", "age": 20});
db.users.insert({"name":"mark","gender":"m", "age": 20});
db.users.insert({"name":"will","gender":"m, "age": 20"});
db.users.insert({"name":"peter","gender":"m", "age": 20});
db.users.insert({"name":"henry","gender":"m", "age": 20});
db.users.insert({"name":"anna","gender":"f", "age": 20});
db.users.insert({"name":"bella","gender":"f", "age": 20});
db.users.insert({"name":"dina","gender":"f", "age": 20});
db.users.insert({"name":"carla","gender":"f", "age": 20});
db.users.insert({"name":"mary","gender":"f", "age": 30});
db.users.insert({"name":"jennifer","gender":"f", "age": 40});
```

I have now 12 users. 6 men and 6 women.
If I run this query to get 3 random men:

```
db.users.aggregate([ 
{ $sample: { size: 3 } },
{ $match: { gender: "m" } }
])
```

I would expect to get exactly 3 male user. Well I don't get that. I get UP TO 3. Actually run this query many times and most of the time I get either 1 or 2 users.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should put the `$match` stage before the `$sample` to ensure you sample from filtered set of male.

Answer (score 1):

The [`$sample`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) size of 3 at the start of the [pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline) will take a random sample of 3 of the 12 users. This could be any combination of course. E.g. **(3F)**, **(2F+1M)**, **(1F+2M)**, **(3M)**. Since your [`$match`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage is after, it works on the documents passed through to it from the `$sample` stage.

Example: If the `$sample` stage passed through **(1F+2M)** then your match stage for male users would only return 2 documents (hence the "UP TO 3" documents you have mentioned).